# Git performance on a Windows mapped drive is poor. Is there a simpler solution?

Tags: windows, git

I would like to use Git in a multi-developer, single development server environment. I realize Git works well when used locally, but due to licensing, test data size, compiler and other server requirements, it is impractical to give each developer a good environment to work in locally.

On this development server, I can carve out a place for each developer. Let's call them *accounts*. Users (and developers) connect to the server and perform their day-to-day functions via a client. This client runs on everyone's local PC, and developers are able to edit files and source code on the server this way. I would love to be able to open up a command line or the GitHub Windows application and have this run alongside the client everyone uses. All Git commands would technically be modifying files on the server. An account is essentially a Windows directory, so I tried mapping the code folder from the server to my PC. A Git repository is set up in this directory. Unfortunately, Git performance is incredibly slow.

**Has anyone in this kind of situation successfully worked around these challenges? Any good alternatives to the mapped-drive approach?**

#### Notes:

1. Everything in my environment is Windows-based. Server 2008 R2, PCs running Windows 7 or 8. All developers are on-site and on the same LAN.
2. I thought maybe posh-git was slowing things down, but performance with Git bash is only slightly better. I even tried to find a good file-sync solution in order to have the Git repo be local, but all seemed to be on the sluggish side and would likely complicate the workflow.
3. My Git repo is right around 55MB. Everything I'm tracking amounts to about 13,000 files across 14 folders. All Git commands perform well and without any delay when I work directly on the server.
4. I'm using the Git version that comes with the GitHub Windows application. I have not done anything to customize the installation at this point.
5. I am on a Windows domain and Homedirs gets mapped to an H: drive, but as far as I can tell, there's no specific mention of this in my environment variables. (I saw some other Stack Overflow questions that talked about Git on Windows being slow, but mine is really only when using a repo on a mapped-drive.)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help point me in the right direction!

Comment: git needs to calculate checksum of every file, so will be slow on network.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to speed up GIT operations on a mapped network drive?